# Return the value of an attribute in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection in MongoDB named (Emotion), it has 13 documents and one of the attributes of the document is (maxEmotion)

I'm using Python, I want to return all the values of that attribute, so at the end I will have 13 results.

I've tried:

```
emotions = db.Emotion.distinct("maxEmotion")
```

But I didn't get the correct results.

This is a picture from the collection:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what the "correct results" should look like?

Comment: {"Happy","Happy","Sad","Scared","Angry","Angry","Happy","Happy","Happy","Happy","Sad","Sad","Happy"}